# How to see my profile from a friends of friends perspective on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy, profile

I can see my profile from the perspective of a 1st level friend, but I would like to see how my profile looks for a specific friend of a friend, or even from a general "friends of friends" perspective.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view from a public perspective or a friend's perspective - but not from a friend of friend's perspective.

[image]

To do this, head over to your profile page & Click on View as...

[image: view as]

Comment: Ok, that is what I was expecting really, but hoped there would be some less known option to do what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is available anymore

Comment: @JasonAxelson not really, it's still around

Comment: @Sathya Ah, for some reason I thought it was on the privacy page.

Comment: Aww that sucks :( I wish FB had this lol.